# What's the name for the job (position)?

Tags: word-choice

How can I possibly call a person whose job is to train (not teach!) people to speak English. It's like Question-Answer, Question-Answer. They don't teach grammar, vocab, reading, writing. They only get people talking. I've been googling it for ages but nothing fits. Speaking trainer - usually refers to public speaking trainers, English speaking trainer - refers to trainers who speak English, Talking trainer - it's like for budgies...
I guess, I'm not quite correct with my search inquiry. Thank you.

Comment: This would be a "coach".

Comment: Sometimes "mentor" although the role can be broader.

Comment: An English Speaking Coach? Is that ok? I'm afraid that "coach" is too general.

Comment: @TatyanaBorovikova It might be good to add "coach" and why you reject that to your question, along with the other things you've considered. (*Coach* doesn't seem wrong to me: why does it to you?)

Comment: @AndrewLeach it doesn' seem wrong to me either. Using only "coach" seems too general, too broad. I want to specify it somehow.

Comment: Is this person speaking English with the “student” or is this person getting two or more “students” speaking to each other? If it is the latter then this person is a facilitator and I will answer.

Comment: What’s wrong with ***language trainer*** or ***English language trainer***?

Comment: @Jim nothing really. I just wanted to stress out that it's mostly about "speaking". Language training (ESL) in general usually involves all aspects, reading, writing, grammar, pronunciation etc. But, you know, there're people who've been studying language for years and they know grammar sometimes better than natives do (to say nothing of their vocab) but they're so much afraid of just opening their mouth and producing some sounds in English.

Comment: @Damila it's the former, I'm afraid

Comment: Google, "English Conversation Coach" and see if that fits?

Comment: English speech coach

Answer (score 0):

Try “language exchange” or “conversation partner.”

For what it’s worth, there are lots of websites and apps out there for this exact purpose, like https://www.hellotalk.com

Good luck!

Comment: @Bitterdreggs. Thanks for the welcome. Can you explain why you downvote me? I answered the question with two possibilities, and never recommend a job. I thought it would be helpful to provide an example of a site that offers this service.

Comment: @Bitterdreggs.Thanks for the reply. Is my answer not self-contained? The link is just an example of an app that offers this service. I will update to try to make this even clearer.